# python3で簡単なAutoencoderを作成したところAttributeErrorが発生する

Tags: python, python3, chainer

ChainerでAutoEncoderを作成して、学習させようしたところ,
以下のようなエラーが発生しました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MNIST_autoenc.py", line 30, in <module>
    y = model(xs[batch:batch+128])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/link.py", line 293, in __call__
    forward = self.forward  # type: ignore
AttributeError: 'AutoEncoder' object has no attribute 'forward'
```

コードは以下の通りです。
修正箇所があればご教授お願いします。

```py
import chainer
import chainer.links as L
import chainer.functions as F
import numpy as np

class AutoEncoder(chainer.Chain):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AutoEncoder, self).__init__(
            l0 = L.Linear(784, 256),
            l1 = L.Linear(256, 784) 
        )

        def __call__(self, x):
            h0 = F.relu(self.l0(x))
            h1 = F.sigmoid(self.l1(h0))
            return h5

train, test = chainer.datasets.get_mnist(ndim=1)
xs, ts = train._datasets
txs, tts = test._datasets

model = AutoEncoder()
model.to_cpu()
optimizer = chainer.optimizers.Adam()
optimizer.setup(model)

for _ in range(1000):
    model.zerograds()
    batch = np.random.randint(0, 60000-128)
    y = model(xs[batch:batch+128])
    acc = F.accuracy(y, rs[batch:batch+128])
    loss = F.softmax_cross_entropy(y, t[batch:batch+128])
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.update()
    if _ % 100 == 0:
        print("epoch:%d --> accuracy:%.4f, loss:%.4f" % (_, acc.data, loss.data))
```

環境は
macbook pro 2015
python3 ver3.7.0
chainer ver6.0.0
numpy 1.17.0

Answer (score 1):

ぱっと見ですが、`def __call__(self, x):`の行からインデントがずれていることに起因していませんかね。

```
        def __call__(self, x):
            h0 = F.relu(self.l0(x))
            h1 = F.sigmoid(self.l1(h0))
            return h5
```

以下のようにしたら、どうなりますか？

```
    def __call__(self, x):
        h0 = F.relu(self.l0(x))
        h1 = F.sigmoid(self.l1(h0))
        return h5
```

`AutoEncoder`に`forward()`も`__call__()`も無いから、`AttributeError`になっているように見えます。

https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/link.py#L293

Comment: ありがとうございます。インデントに全然気が付きませんでした！

Comment: @monte これで解決しましたか？